# Receiving ReferenceError when trying to access function parameter in Puppeteer call

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have a function that select filters on the website using Puppeteer.

The problem is when I pass function parameters and console log them before they are passed to `page.select` or `page.$eval` then they are logged correctly, but the function says that the variable is undefined.

```
private static async selectFilterOptions( { skillFilter, skillMinValue }) {
    try {
      console.log({ skillFilter, skillMinValue }); // { skillFilter: '1', skillMinValue: '30' }

      await this.page.waitForSelector(".containerMain");
      await this.page.select("select[name='skill']", skillFilter);
      await this.page.$eval("input[name='range']", el => el.value = skillMinValue); // Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: skillMinValue is not defined
      
      await this.page.click("input[name='Search']");

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs describe [page.$eval](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) function this way:

```
page.$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])
```

*Args* here are any number of comma-separated arguments to use inside of page.evaluate (optional, must be serializeable).

So in your case here's how to pass the value from node context to browser context:

```
await this.page.$eval("input[name='range']", el => el.value = skillMinValue, skillMinValue);
```